# javascript set timeout is not working

Tags: javascript

I expected the below code snippet to print out the console log after pausing for every 1 sec.

But the code snippet executes instantaneously (*prints out 100 times though*) with the following output.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong ?

[image]

```js
let i = 0;
for (; i < 100; i++) {
  setTimeout(console.log("test"), 1000);
}
console.log('Loop Done');
console.log('Value of i ==>' + i);
```

Comment: You are calling `console.log` right away, and also `setTimeout` is asynchronous.

Comment: Hi again, Aaron. Please see what I did last time to your code. Just click `<>` and click tidy before saving

Comment: Your telling setTimeout to execute the `result` of a `console .log` a 100 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, you are calling `console.log` right away, and also `setTimeout` is asynchronous and thus it is nonblocking.

One of the correct ways to do it would be

```
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    setTimeout(() => console.log("test"), 1000 * i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are actually setting a timeout for the `return` value of `console.log`, i.e., `undefined`, instead of an actual function.

`setTimeout` requires a `function` as the first argument in order for it to work. You have passed `undefined`. To fix this, there are 2 ways.

#### Pass a function that calls `console.log`

```
setTimeout(function () {
  console.log("test");
}, 100);
```

In ES6, that would be much shorter:

```
setTimeout(() => console.log("test"), 100);
```

#### Bind arguments to `console.log`

```
setTimeout(console.log.bind(undefined, "test"), 100);
```

`bind()`-ing arguments to a function is like telling the function to to execute with the arguments we are giving it. The function is not executed immediately when you call `bind`, but the arguments are stored.

Also, as a side-note, the first argument we passed for `bind`, i.e., `undefined`, is the `this` value for the function. We do not care about the `this` value of `console.log`, and we want to pass only `"test"`, we write `undefined` as the `this` value.

Comment: To be picky, it really should be `console` instead of `undefined` because `.log` is a property of `console` when called normally.